# Why did this cake fail?

Tags: baking, cake

I made [this cake](https://www.bigoven.com/recipe/pareve-apple-walnut-cake/2322487) in a borrowed bundt pan (i.e., I'm not used to baking in it), which I greased with cooking spray. This was the result:

[image]

Not only did large sections stick to the pan and tear out upon removal, but there's that thick semi-burnt crust on the surface.

- The tear-out suggests that the pan wasn't greased properly, but I typically get pretty good coverage with that spray.
- The semi-burnt crust suggests that the oven was too hot, but, while I've never actually tested the oven, I've used it for years with no problems, so I'm pretty confident that it's accurate.

Does anyone have a thought as to what happened here?

Comment: What material is the Bundt pan made of? Have you made the recipe before?

Comment: Does the method specify details on greasing the pan? I find most bundt pans utterly unforgiving, and find that cooking spray just isn't enough to prevent sticking. Using butter (or lard or Crisco) and flour has been my only successful option. But I've also given up on making bundt cakes a decade ago, and found a great bakery instead. 

Comment: @Stephie Some unknown metal. And yes, I have, but it was in a straight-sided tube pan.

Comment: @AMtwo No details on the greasing protocol. And the preferred vessel is a straight-sided tube pan with a removable bottom, but the only thing I could get my hands on was a bundt pan.

Comment: I like to grease and flour a bundt pan. Grease with cooking spray, oil or solid fat (lard/shortening/butter). Add a spoonful or two of flour, then tip the pan in all directions to get an even coating of flour. Turn the pan over and tap gently to remove the excess flour.

Comment: @csk : and if you're making a chocolate cake, dust with cocoa instead of flour.

Comment: @joe Cocoa is expensive, flour is cheap. I use flour even on a chocolate cake. If you use a thin layer of both grease and flour, it's not terribly visible on the outside of the cake. And a dusting of powdered sugar on the finished cake will hide any visible bits of flour.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Batters full of starches and sugars are always sticky, how you prevent it from sticking partly depends on the plan. Some pans have coatings which while called non-stick aren't, but do reduce sticking somewhat. On pans like these often buttering is sufficient, and 'normal' cake pan shapes allow you to loosen the sides by running a knife around the side, so even if they stick you can free the cake. Putting a piece of baking paper on the bottom of a flat bottomed pan is a sure-fire way of preventing issues.

When you have an odd shape like a bundt, paper won't work, and you can't afford anything sticking, so the best way to ensure it frees is to generously butter (not oil or spray) the pan and then flour it. You can also make cake release, which can be sprayed or brushed on, using equal volumes of flour, oil and shortening.

Comment: Why not spray the pan?

Comment: Oil doesn't stay where you put it @Alex, solid fat won't go anywhere.